# By mistake commit some code in GIT! causing confliction error

Tags: java, git, liferay, bitbucket

I made some changes inside ServiceImpl.java and when i was about to commit in repository it shows me you had some changes in .project file. The changes are...

```
<name>org.eclipse.wst.common.project.facet.core.builder</name>
<arguments>
</arguments>
    </buildCommand>
     <buildCommand>
```

and by mistake I commited it in repository, And I saw some conflict error.
I removed the code from project` file! and recommit it, and i saw the same error again!

The problem is I have done many commits since then.
How would I cancel this faulty commit?

Comment: can you revert it back ?

Comment: yeah i want to revert it back... i used git reset --hard HEAD but it brings me at last commit. any other way to solve this problem

Comment: @VonC 

While merging code in GIT (Bitbucket), after pull request I got an issue src/main/webapp/css/main.css (conflicts) the code is fine in Eclipse but in Bitbucket view its showing 3 more lines added in code having some text. like

<<<<<<< destination:f27cd37fb7008c0d18f63514ca44ceacbaa3c658

============================

>>>>>>> source:95de515e0203585db3c4f1084e37ade6dcc08ed2
when i try to edit it the appear line becomes disappear :(

Comment: @Akash Yes, I saw http://stackoverflow.com/a/23358089/6309, but if this is a BitBucket editor feature, I would first clone that BitBucket repo locally, and open in a simple text editor that filr, to see if those merge merkers are still there. Then choose the part you want to keep, remove the merge markers, add, commit and push back.

Comment: VonC i am still unable to resolve this i tried everything :-/ 
I would be very thankful if you help me :( as i wasted too much time on this.
i can give you my teamviewer credential :-/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your commit consisted of only the one file, you could do a:

```
git reset --hard HEAD~
```

That will bring you back to the state *before* your last commit.

Make sure you don't have any other modifications in progress though (or stash them first).

---

The [OP Akash](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3454205/akash) adds though [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23126411/by-mistake-commit-some-code-in-git-causing-confliction-error/23126733#comment35358521_23126733):

> i did commit manytimes

You have tow choices:

- a `git rebase --interactive` let you reorder past commits, including *dropping* the one you don't want.
  That changes the history though, meaning you will need a git push -force (if you did already push those commits before): if you are pushing to a pull request branch, this ok. If you are pushing to a public branch (cloned by other), that can be problematic.
- a `git revert` (see "[Revert to previous Git commit](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4114122/6309)"), in order to create a *new* commit which will cancel the modification of the past commit.
  This is safer, and doesn't change the history.

Comment: Thanks VonC but as i mentiond i want to bring myself at last merged code! any suggetion?

Comment: @Akash did you use the reset eventually?

Comment: My situation is, i am new to bitbucket... last night i made some changes in java code and at the time of commit, it shows me you have changed 2 file one is java and another one is .project, by mistake i pulled the request for both files. after ward i got some confliction error, and i reset the code as it was! i tried to recommit it. it commited successfully and i pulled request for them. i know i did some stupid stuffs Please help:-/ @VonC

Comment: @Akash so the reset could help, in order for you to redo your changes, no? (I mean, you did mark the answer as "valid")

Comment: As far i think, reset brings you to the previous commit? and i did commit manytimes @VonC any help

Comment: @Akash Ok. I have completed the answer in order to present the two choices you have.

Comment: @Akash see also http://christoph.ruegg.name/blog/git-howto-revert-a-commit-already-pushed-to-a-remote-reposit.html